# Header and subnav are a mess, need assistance

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

Hi friendly web experts,

I am six months in learning to code websites and have a big project due but the changes to header & subnav have made things all wonky and don't look right at all. The logo should sit above the nav menu in a box with drop shadow and radius corners and the sub nav should pop down in a different color when the submenu is activated. Right now the margin spacing at the top and below the navigation isn't appearing right either.

I'm a total rookie, so any advice or coding help would be so appreciated!

[See Header example screenshot, what it should look like vs what it is appearing like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAvsK.jpg)

HTML

```html
<div id="headerWrap" class="hidden-xs">


</div>

<div class="headerWrap hidden-xs">
  <div class="headerWrapInner">
    <div class="container container-smooth">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div id="headerLogo">
            <a href="img">
              <img src="img" style="width:220px;height:auto;">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <ul>


            <nav role="navigation">
              <div class="headerWrap-mainNavigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li id="menu-item-259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-226 current_page_item active menu-item-259 active"><a href="visit">Visit</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1040" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1040"><a href="memberships">Memberships</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-261" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-261"><a href="exhibits">Exhibits</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1134" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1134"><a href="parties-events">Parties/Events</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-264"><a href="preschool">Preschool</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1157" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1157"><a href="contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="headerWrap-subnav">
                  <div class="container container-smooth">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div id="informationSubmenu" style="padding-left:0px;">
                          <ul>
                            <li id="menu-item-427" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-427"><a href="visit/museum-store/">Museum Store</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-428" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-428"><a href="visit/faqs/">FAQs</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-1113" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1113"><a href="category/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-1109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1109"><a href="visit/our-story/">Our Story</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
```

CSS

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.lead { font-size: 24px; }
}
small,
.small { font-size: 75%; }
mark,
.mark { background-color: #fcf8e3; padding: .2em; }
.text-left { text-align: left; }
.text-right { text-align: right; }
.text-left { text-align: left; }
.text-justify { text-align: justify; }
.text-nowrap { white-space: nowrap; }
.text-lowercase { text-transform: lowercase; }
.text-uppercase,
.initialism { text-transform: uppercase; }
.text-capitalize { text-transform: capitalize; }
.text-muted { color: #777777; }
.text-primary { color: #337ab7; }
a.text-primary:hover,
a.text-primary:focus { color: #286090; }
.text-success { color: #3c763d; }
a.text-success:hover,
a.text-success:focus { color: #2b542c; }
.text-info { color: #31708f; }
a.text-info:hover,
a.text-info:focus { color: #245269; }
.text-warning { color: #8a6d3b; }
a.text-warning:hover,
a.text-warning:focus { color: #66512c; }
.text-danger { color: #a94442; }
a.text-danger:hover,
a.text-danger:focus { color: #843534; }
.bg-primary { color: #fff; }
.bg-primary { background-color: #337ab7; }
a.bg-primary:hover,
a.bg-primary:focus { background-color: #286090; }
.bg-success { background-color: #dff0d8; }
a.bg-success:hover,
a.bg-success:focus { background-color: #c1e2b3; }
.bg-info { background-color: #d9edf7; }
a.bg-info:hover,
a.bg-info:focus { background-color: #afd9ee; }
.bg-warning { background-color: #fcf8e3; }
a.bg-warning:hover,
a.bg-warning:focus { background-color: #f7ecb5; }
.bg-danger { background-color: #f2dede; }
a.bg-danger:hover,
a.bg-danger:focus { background-color: #e4b9b9; }
.page-header { padding-bottom: 10px; margin: 44px 0 22px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee; }
ul,
ol { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 11px; }
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ul,
ol ol { margin-bottom: 0; }
.list-unstyled { padding-left: 0; list-style: none; }
.list-inline { padding-left: 0; list-style: none; margin-left: -5px; }
.list-inline > li { display: inline-block; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; }
dl { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 22px; }
dt,
dd { line-height: 1.42857; }
dt { font-weight: bold; }
dd { margin-left: 0; }
.dl-horizontal dd:before,
.dl-horizontal dd:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.dl-horizontal dd:after { clear: both; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.dl-horizontal dt { float: left; width: 160px; clear: left; text-align: right; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; }
.dl-horizontal dd { margin-left: 180px; }
}
abbr[title],
abbr[data-original-title] { cursor: help; border-bottom: 1px dotted #777777; }
.initialism { font-size: 90%; }
blockquote { padding: 11px 22px; margin: 0 0 22px; font-size: 20px; border-left: 5px solid #eeeeee; }
blockquote p:last-child,
blockquote ul:last-child,
blockquote ol:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
blockquote footer,
blockquote small,
blockquote .small { display: block; font-size: 80%; line-height: 1.42857; color: #777777; }
blockquote footer:before,
blockquote small:before,
blockquote .small:before { content: '\2014 \00A0'; }
.blockquote-reverse,
blockquote.pull-right { padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 0; border-right: 5px solid #eeeeee; border-left: 0; text-align: right; }
.blockquote-reverse footer:before,
.blockquote-reverse small:before,
.blockquote-reverse .small:before,
blockquote.pull-right footer:before,
blockquote.pull-right small:before,
blockquote.pull-right .small:before { content: ''; }
.blockquote-reverse footer:after,
.blockquote-reverse small:after,
.blockquote-reverse .small:after,
blockquote.pull-right footer:after,
blockquote.pull-right small:after,
blockquote.pull-right .small:after { content: '\00A0 \2014'; }
address { margin-bottom: 22px; font-style: normal; line-height: 1.42857; }
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp { font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace; }
code { padding: 2px 4px; font-size: 90%; color: #c7254e; background-color: #f9f2f4; border-radius: 4px; }
kbd { padding: 2px 4px; font-size: 90%; color: #fff; background-color: #333; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
kbd kbd { padding: 0; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold; box-shadow: none; }
pre { display: block; padding: 10.5px; margin: 0 0 11px; font-size: 15px; line-height: 1.42857; word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word; color: #333333; background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; }
pre code { padding: 0; font-size: inherit; color: inherit; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent; border-radius: 0; }
.pre-scrollable { max-height: 340px; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: Is there a specific question?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using JSFiddle or so

Comment: Hi @Armin, yes how do I make the coding resemble the example image?

Comment: You should probably read a link that @NikhilNanjappa posted

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa here is the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fhkp439r/#&togetherjs=Gm1j4vbvhv

Thanks!

Comment: @Armin I'm new to web dev, so not sure where the problem is. Any help is appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAvsK.jpg

Comment: Comment section is already too long. Please read link about asking a question. For a start don't include your PHP code, but your generated HTML code. I am sure you will notice that your fiddle link is not even remotely similar to the image you posted. Try to make something that people can analyse without having to recreate your image.

Comment: @armin How do I find my generated HTML code?

Comment: One of the ways is to look at your source-code of the page. (For example click right-click and choose "View page source")

Comment: @armin more like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/fhkp439r/1/#&togetherjs=Gm1j4vbvhv

Comment: Looks better, but still I am not sure many people will bother to answer. From what I saw, you can try adding position: absolute to your logo. Then work with positioning.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you just need to add a background-color to your image, align it to the position you want it in and add a bottom border radius.

I have done all the following in this JSfiddle, this should help give you an idea of what you need to do:

Obviously you replace it with you own colors and logo.

https://jsfiddle.net/fbbq58t5/

```
.image {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 325px;
  height: 240px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
```

**Please vote up if it helps !**